# Only display element on hover and user is grabbing file

Tags: html, css, input-type-file

I've got the following setup:

- a button which says: "upload your file here", which is just a plain `<input type="file" multiple>`
- When the user goes into finder and wants to drop the file, I want to show a larger area where they can drop the file, since the button isn't very big. This should only be available when the user hovers over the 'bigger input' AND is holding a file.

How do I go about implementing #2?

I have seen a stylechange on this site: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ when the user 'hovers with a file' above the upload area, but haven't been able to figure out how they do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript for File Drop Style Change :

check this **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/npxp7kkr/)** :

```
// file drag hover
function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a function to the eventtype you want to listen to (dragover, dragenter, dragstart, dragend and dragleave) and make sure this function has at least one argument (the event). Then use event.dataTransfer. Without more details of how you want to implement it, giving example code is hard.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer

FYI the dropzonejs you mentioned uses:

```
return function(e) {
  var efct;
  try {
    efct = e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed;
  } catch (_error) {}
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move' === efct || 'linkMove' === efct ? 'move' : 'copy';
  noPropagation(e);
  return _this.emit("dragover", e);
}
```

Above code was bound to "dragover"

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! I think both answers are good, so I decided to share the points a bit.